# Connecting two networks on the same range with WireGurard

Tags: networking, site-to-site-vpn, wireguard

I have a problem. I need to connect two networks in the same IP range with Site-to-site VPN. Is it possible?

Network #1 (`n1`) is `192.168.1.0/24` and network #2 (`n2`) is also in the same range - `192.168.1.0/24`

Is there a way I can set up a site to site network between both networks without changing the local IP range in each network?

I was thinking of something like this.

`N1` stays on `192.168.1.0/24` and to access other devices in `N1` it uses the same IP range. But a way to route to `N2` using say `192.168.2.0/24` from N1 but at the same time let `N2` to stay on `192.168.1.0/24` locally with `N2`. Is it possible?

So:

`N1` stays in `192.168.1.0/24`
`N2` stays in `192.168.1.0/24`
Site to site VPN with WireGuard network stays in `10.20.40.0/24`

`N1` to be able to access `N2` using `192.168.2.0/24` and to other devices in `N1` using 192.168.1.0/24
`N2` to be able to access `N1` using `192.168.2.0/24` and to other devices in `N2` using 192.168.1.0/24

I know this might be stupid - but if it isn't I'd love it. This is because we do not want to change the local network range for either IPs.

Comment: You don't have to renumber both networks, only one.

Comment: OK, how do I do this without changing the network range of each network locally

Comment: You don't. You renumber one or both networks.

Comment: @MichaelHampton could you please elaborate. I don't think I understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: You have to do what you say you don't want to do. You understand this perfectly well.

Comment: And you are sure there is no other way? @MichaelHampton

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119372/discussion-between-mathew-paret-and-michael-hampton).

Comment: Change `N2` from `192.168.1.0/24` to `192.168.2.0/24`. Update any `N2` hosts that have hardcoded references to old IPv4 address `192.168.1.X` to new addresses `192.168.2.X`. That should be everything.